# Extracting elements with attributes using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

In the following XM, how can I extract nodes, where the price is higher than 25 and currency, is "usd"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price currency = "usd">29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price currency="gbp">39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood Your task right, something like this can help You:

```
//book[./price[@currency='usd' and text()>25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//book[price/@currency = "usd"][price > 25]
```

will select all books that cost more than $25 USD.